# submit logon in credential provider

Tags: c#, credential-providers

I have read this [article](https://syfuhs.net/2017/10/15/creating-custom-windows-credential-providers-in-net) to develop my custom credential provider.

Now I want to test code attached with the article in [GitHub](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/CredProvider.NET).

- I run

  > install.reg file.
- run the code and show GUI in login screen by change scenario

  ```
   private static bool IsSupportedScenario(_CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO cpus)

       {

         switch (cpus)
          {

           case _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO.CPUS_CREDUI:
              return true;

          case _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO.CPUS_UNLOCK_WORKSTATION:
              return true;

          case _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO.CPUS_LOGON:
              return true;
          case _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO.CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD:
          case _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO.CPUS_PLAP:
          case _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_USAGE_SCENARIO.CPUS_INVALID:
          default:
              return false;
      }
  }
  ```

the question is how can I submit an inserted username/password and log in successfully if correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this sample [windows-credentials-provider](https://github.com/phaetto/windows-credentials-provider). Change usage scenarios as above in the question and put username/password in this function.

```
public int GetSerialization(out _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE pcpgsr,
            out _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION pcpcs, out string ppszOptionalStatusText,
            out _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon)
        {
            Log.LogMethodCall();

            try
            {
                pcpgsr = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE.CPGSR_RETURN_CREDENTIAL_FINISHED;
                pcpcs = new _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION();

                var username = "Domain\\username";
                var password = "password";
                var inCredSize = 0;
                var inCredBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(0);

                if (!PInvoke.CredPackAuthenticationBuffer(0, username, password, inCredBuffer, ref inCredSize))
                {
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(inCredBuffer);
                    inCredBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(inCredSize);

                    if (PInvoke.CredPackAuthenticationBuffer(0, username, password, inCredBuffer, ref inCredSize))
                    {
                        ppszOptionalStatusText = string.Empty;
                        pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON.CPSI_SUCCESS;

                        pcpcs.clsidCredentialProvider = Guid.Parse(Constants.CredentialProviderUID);
                        pcpcs.rgbSerialization = inCredBuffer;
                        pcpcs.cbSerialization = (uint)inCredSize;

                        RetrieveNegotiateAuthPackage(out var authPackage);
                        pcpcs.ulAuthenticationPackage = authPackage;

                        return HResultValues.S_OK;
                    }

                    ppszOptionalStatusText = "Failed to pack credentials";
                    pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON.CPSI_ERROR;
                    return HResultValues.E_FAIL;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // In case of any error, do not bring down winlogon
            }
            finally
            {
                shouldAutoLogin = false; // Block auto-login from being stupid
            }

            pcpgsr = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE.CPGSR_NO_CREDENTIAL_NOT_FINISHED;
            pcpcs = new _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION();
            ppszOptionalStatusText = string.Empty;
            pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon = _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON.CPSI_NONE;
            return HResultValues.E_NOTIMPL;
        }
```

Finally I can test .net custom credential provider.

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching for this : [LogonUser - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) ?

Answer (score 0):

This was hanging me up for awhile, too. But it was just my misunderstanding of how the credential providers work and how to implement their interfaces.

You don't actually "submit" the credentials yourself. You just serialize them as shown in the accepted answer above by populating _CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION, and Windows takes care of actually submitting them to Winlogon.exe

You can then check the result of the submittal in the ReportResult() method.